# Cypress: is using within() better to find a child?

Tags: javascript, cypress

Cypress has the option to use within() to scope all subsequent cy commands to within that element.

In the case where i want to find a descendant, is it any better to use within() or these other two formats? I understand > is direct descendant while the space is the same with within() where it checks all descendants. The reason i had had to use both tags in my get() is because the tagB is used several times in the page, so i had to use tagA that makes it unique.

Code:

```
<div class="ClassA" data-qa="tagA">
   <button class="ClassB" data-qa="tagB"/>
</div>
```

**Which is better?**

`cy.get('[data-qa="tagA"] [data-qa="tagB"]').click()`

`cy.get('[data-qa="tagA"] > [data-qa="tagB"]').click()`

```
cy.get('[data-qa="tagA"]').within(() => {
  cy.get('[data-qa="tagB"]').click()
})
```

Comment: The second version is not the same as the first and third.  Using `>` enforces immediate children only.  Without it, the children found can be on any nested level.

Comment: Which one is better, is a relative question.  Different scenarios may benefit more from one vs the other.

Comment: I updated my sample code.
But yeah, all three 3 works in my case, but was just thinking which is better or more appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

1.In my opinion, this works better

```
cy.get('[data-qa="tagA"]').within(() => {
  cy.get('[data-qa="tagB"]').click()
})
```

because you can reuse the `[data-qa="tagA"]` locator in the above statement or somewhere else as well. But in case of `[data-qa="tagA"] > [data-qa="tagB"]` or `[data-qa="tagA"] [data-qa="tagB"]` you have to repeat the locator `[data-qa="tagA"]` twice.

2.Apart from `within()` you can also use `find()`, which helps you find descendent DOM elements of a specific selector.

```
cy.get('[data-qa="tagA"]').find('[data-qa="tagB"]').then(($ele) => {
  $ele.click()
})
```

3.You can also use `children()` or `parents()`. Suppose your HTML DOM is like this:

```
<ul class='main-nav'>
  <li>Overview</li>
  <li>Getting started
    <ul class='sub-nav'>
      <li>Install</li>
      <li class='active'>Build</li>
      <li>Test</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Using `children()`:

```
// yields
//  <li>Install</li>
//  <li class='active'>Build</li>
//  <li>Test</li>
cy.get('ul.sub-nav').children()
```

Using `parents()`:

```
// yields [.sub-nav, li, .main-nav]
cy.get('li.active').parents()
```